# Openvpn routing all traffc based on client side configuration

Tags: openvpn

I was able to redirect all the traffic on the openvpn server using on server side configuration:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

but in this way all the clients will redirect the traffic via the vpn.

How can I enabled/disabled this on the client side openvpn configuration? 
Maybe I don't want some clients to redirect all the traffic.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the `route-nopull` and `route-metric` directives in your client config.

Comment: @Lenniey thanks. In the case that the server is not configured with the redirect-gateway, can you setup the client configuration to route all the traffic via the openvpn?

Comment: You can, but you have to manually alter routing tables / firewall configs on your client side to redirect all traffic through your VPN server. It's not _that_ trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `client-config-dir` directive in OpenVPN to provide different configurations for different clients. You can find details of the directive in https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html.

The principle is that you create a directory where per-client configuration files are, and add the directory name after `client-config-dir` directive. Then, inside the directory you add files which are named after the OpenVPN client names.

In those files, you can add:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

for the clients whose traffic you want to get routed via the VPN. For other clients, you don't create such files.

Comment: Well, I assumed (maybe wrongly) that OP can't change the server configs. If that's not the case, your answer is clearly the right one.